# Замена параметров формулы в String числами

Tags: java, строки

Пользователь вводит формулу в виде `String` состоящую из букв и знаков
`-` и `+` например:

```
String s = "b+c-a+b";
```

Если `a=4`  `b=5`  `c=2`, то как сделать проще чтобы указанный String превратился  в соответственно  `s = "5+2-4+5";` ?

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();;
    String s = "b+c-a+b";
    ArrayList<String> arraylist2 = new ArrayList<String>(     
                                            Arrays.asList("4","5", "2")); 
    ArrayList<String> arraylist1 = new ArrayList<String>(   
                                            Arrays.asList("a","b", "c")); 
    char cInput;

    for (int k = 0; k<arraylist1.size(); k++){
        map.put(arraylist1.get(k), arraylist2.get(k));
    }

    String res = "";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
        cInput = s.charAt(i);
        String tmp = Character.toString(cInput);
    if (map.containsKey(tmp))       
            tmp = map.get(tmp);
        res +=  tmp;

        System.out.println(res);
    }
    System.out.println(res);
```

Результат:  5+2-4+5

Answer (score 4):

Если работаете с заменой символов, то логичнее в мапе хранить `Character`, а не `String`. Так же, если собираете `String` из символов или из строк, то лучше и проще использовать `StringBuilder`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Character, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put('a', '4');
    map.put('b', '5');
    map.put('c', '2');

    String s = "b+c-a+b";

    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (char aChar : chars) {
        if (map.containsKey(aChar)) {
            result.append(map.get(aChar));
        } else {
            result.append(aChar);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Либо можно воспользоваться модным нынче `Stream API`.

```
StringBuilder result = s.chars()
            .mapToObj(i -> map.containsKey((char) i) ? map.get((char) i) : (char) i)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append);
```